# Private class in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm creating a cocoapod that I want to use in one of my project. I create some classes that I want accessible from the project with my pod. I created some classes that I don't want accessible from the project but my classes in my pod need them. Is there a way to prevent some classes to be accessible but used by my pod classes.

Thanks